# Why Sphinx does not find module 'sphinxcontrib.serializinghtml'

Tags: python-3.x, python-sphinx

Since I updated Sphinx from 1.7 to 2.2.0 an attempt to create the documentation ends at once with

> Could not import extension sphinx.builders.epub3 (exception: No module
>   named 'sphinxcontrib.serializinghtml')

I am starting Sphinx from pyCharm 2018.2 under Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 with Python 3.7. Environment variable "Path" contains the path to python 37, python 37/lib, python 37/lib/site-packages, python 37/dlls. The module serializinghtml exists in "Python 37\Lib\site-packages\sphinxcontrib\".

Can anybody help please?

Best regards 
Humbalan

Comment: Always check the [issue tracker](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+serializinghtml).

Comment: Thank you, Steve, reinstalled the old version.

Comment: same for me, I'm using the automodapi extension.